# Why is extra space being added to the frame?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

So I'm adding this code to a JFrame which has other layout managers and components in them.

```
    private JPanel testing123() {
    JPanel j = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    jbtOk = new JButton("OK");
    jbtOk.setMnemonic('K');
    jbtExit = new JButton("Exit");
    jbtExit.setMnemonic('x');

    add(jbtOk);
    add(jbtExit);
    j.add(jbtOk);
    j.add(jbtExit);
    return j;
}
```

Without this code, the JFrame looks fine, but when I add it, it adds a large amount of empty space under these two buttons. Why is this happening?

[image]

This replicates it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

JButton jbtOk, jbtExit;

JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));

public Test() {

    super("t");
    //setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);
    JPanel test = test();
    JPanel testing = testing();
    JPanel testing123 = testing123();
    p.add(test);
    p.add(testing);
    p.add(testing123);
    this.getContentPane().add(p);
    pack();
}

private JPanel test() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel labelFields = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
    labelFields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("m"));
    p.add(gui);
    p.add(labelFields);
    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));
    labels.setBorder(new TitledBorder("a"));
    JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));
    fields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("b"));

    p.add(labels);
    p.add(fields);
    add(fields);
    add(p);
    return gui;
}

private JPanel testing() {
    JPanel guiCenter = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    guiCenter.setBorder(new TitledBorder("n"));
    guiCenter.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5,30)));
    gui.add(guiCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    return guiCenter;
}

private JPanel testing123() {
    JPanel j = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    jbtOk = new JButton("OK");
    jbtOk.setMnemonic('K');
    jbtExit = new JButton("Exit");
    jbtExit.setMnemonic('x');

    //add(jbtOk);
    //add(jbtExit);
    j.add(jbtOk);
    j.add(jbtExit);
    return j;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would go a LONG way to helping understand your problem...

Comment: Also screenshot of your meaning of *large amount of empty space* might be helpful

Comment: We need to see where you're adding the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.  Nothing here would cause extraneous space.  Except maybe the fact that you're adding the buttons twice: once to the `JPanel`, and once to the `JFrame` (which should do nothing, since a `JFrame` is basically an empty, invisible container).

Comment: Could it be because my main panel is gridlayout?

Comment: Screen shot _without_ [a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) still doesn't seem to do it for me. There could be any number of things. Glad you decided to follow the comment of the call for screen shot, but we also need to see more relevant code.

Comment: I honestly have been working on a mcve for the past hour and it's not even remotely working properly. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you trying to make some kind of dialog box notifying the user of an error or something similar? If I'm correct, did you consider using [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)?

Comment: Here's what you do, copy and paste your code to another java file, start taking out code one by one (testing it as you take items out) that you know has no relevance to this problem. When you hit something that takes away the problem, put it back in and run it to see if it runs. It if does then paste the code here. The points is, we need to see more relevant code. If not a runnable program, then at least _everything_ where you're adding components anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What look exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @peeskillet I want to get rid of the extra space under the OK and Exit buttons.

Comment: Tip for the future:  A [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a layout problem rarely needs any `ActionListener` or `KeyListener` attached, and that can save some lines of code (to make it 'minimal').  The buttons are really only 'placeholders' for 'will do later'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to get rid of the extra space under the OK and Exit buttons."

The problem is you are using the `GridLayout` that will make all the `JPanel` equal size. What you should do instead is wrap the first four `JPanel` in `GridLayout`, then keep the default `BorderLayout` of the `JFrame`, add the `JPanel` to `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the `JFrame` and add the buttons `JPanel` to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. This should solve the problem

```
public Test() {

    super("t");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
    JPanel test = test();
    JPanel testing = testing();
    JPanel testing123 = testing123();
    p.add(test);
    p.add(testing);
    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);             <---
    add(testing123, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);  <---
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

[image]

Complete running code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    JButton jbtOk, jbtExit;

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));

    public Test() {

        super("t");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel test = test();
        JPanel testing = testing();
        JPanel testing123 = testing123();
        p.add(test);
        p.add(testing);
        add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(testing123, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel test() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel labelFields = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        labelFields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("m"));
        p.add(gui);
        p.add(labelFields);
        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));
        labels.setBorder(new TitledBorder("a"));
        JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));
        fields.setBorder(new TitledBorder("b"));

        p.add(labels);
        p.add(fields);
        return gui;
    }

    private JPanel testing() {
        JPanel guiCenter = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        guiCenter.setBorder(new TitledBorder("n"));
        guiCenter.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 30)));
        gui.add(guiCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return guiCenter;
    }

    private JPanel testing123() {
        JPanel j = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jbtOk = new JButton("OK");
        jbtOk.setMnemonic('K');
        jbtExit = new JButton("Exit");
        jbtExit.setMnemonic('x');

        j.add(jbtOk);
        j.add(jbtExit);

        return j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having such a difficult time and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: See how much difference a MCTRE makes. Keep that in mind next time ;)